# Looking for good DLNA renderer (player) for Windows 7 (32 bit)

Tags: windows-7, dlna, video-player

I'm looking for good DLNA renderer (player) software, comparable with the standard Windows Media Player for supported formats/codecs but with a few **extra features**:

- it should work **without visible window** (maybe, as a service or just with hidden window)
- it should display pictures and videos on **full screen** by commands from DLNA player (DLNA AVControlPoint)
- it should follow commands from DLNA AVControlPoint; for example, on close connection, the full screen window should silently disappear. Other commands (play, pause, volume) also must be supported
- it should **try to pause** other playing media on PC during DLNA rendering, and resume when DLNA connection will be closed.

So, I'm looking for DLNA renderer similar to built-in renderers to smart TV sets. My TV (Hisense 4K) has built-in DLNA renderer but I don't like it for some reasons. Also, my TV's renderer doesn't supports some formats but I do have a HTPC, running on Windows 7, connected as a main video input.

Will be good to have a free and/or open source but paid software is OK too. I'm only looking for good functionality.